# https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Readmore.js](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js) plugin. I looked up various solutions for my following issue but none of them seemed to be perfect.

I want to add a function which collapses the previously expanded article - if any, when readmore is pressed.

Thank's to Josh, I manage to flag a variable `isOpen` as `true` or `false` when an article is expanded/collapsed. Now I'm trying to figure out how to collapse the an article when a new one is expanded.

```
<script>
$('#info').readmore({

moreLink: '<a href="#">More examples and options</a>',
maxHeight: 390,
afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
if(! expanded) { // The "Close" link was clicked
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 100 } );
}
}
});

$('article').readmore({maxHeight: 240});


var isOpen = true;
$('article').readmore({
afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {

if (expanded) {
  isOpen = true;
}
if(! expanded) { 
  isOpen = false;    }
  }
});

$('article').readmore({
beforeToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {

if (isOpen) {

}
  }
}); 
    </script>
```

Thanks already...

Comment: It may be helpful to include the code you've tried.

Answer (score -1):

Just set a flag every time you open an article, and when you expand another article, have it check for flagged (open) articles and close them.

First part I just took this directly from the site and changed it. Sets flags after toggling.

```
var isOpen = true;

$('article').readmore({
afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {

if (expanded) {
  isOpen = true;
}
if(! expanded) { 
  isOpen = false;    }
  }
});
```

Next you just use beforeToggle to check if a flag is activated, and if so, close the article.

To be honest, especially since you're not super experienced, you should just learn how to do what this plugin does yourself. That'll help you learn a lot quicker.

All it does is set the div block style to display: none; Literally, that just makes it disappear, while still being existent. You can achieve the same effect this way:

```
 document.getElementById('article1').style.display = "none";
```

When you want the div block with id article1 to re-appear, presumably onClick then just make it appear:

```
 document.getElementById('article1').style.display = "block";
```

It might even be better to make a smooth transition using CSS. Then just use JavaScript to change style or pseudo-classes in CSS (like :hover)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not very experienced. Do you mind showing me the code inside the readmore.js file?

Comment: I'm sorry I would Upvote you but I can't. I really appreciate your help. I manage to assign variable as a block is expanded and collapsed (with isOpen - truth/false ) proven but the firebug DOM, but how do I collapse a previous article if the function just has an impact on the article itself, as far as I understand. Doesn't each article has to have some kind of id to identify the expanded one or I have to have a function which collapses every article which the original function applies to except the newly clicked one?